# How to save multiple blender scripts (text-files) at once?

Tags: python, scripting, text-editor

I want to write a script that saves all the text files inside a Blender file. Is there a way I can access the text files as a list and then select them individually?

Heres my script so far:

```
import bpy
import datetime

file_destination = 'D:\\Sync Cloud\\Sync\\BLENDER PYTHON SCRIPTS\\Mass Saves By Date'

# GET SCRIPTS
all_scripts = bpy.data.texts
num_of_scripts = int((str(all_scripts).split('[')[1]).split(']')[0])

# GET DATE AND TIME
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = str(now).split(' ')[0]
time = (str(now).split(' ')[1]).split('.')[0]

# GET BLENDER FILE NAME
path = str(bpy.data.filepath).split('\\')
file_path_num = len(path) - 1
file_name = path[file_path_num].split('.blend')[0]

i=0
for x in range(0,num_of_scripts):
    txt_script = bpy.data.texts[i]

    # DELETE A .py
    script_name = (str(txt_script).split("\"")[1]).split('.py')[0]
    if 'Text' not in script_name:

        py_filename = date +'_'+time+'_'+file_name+'_'+script_name+'.py'

        # SAVE SCRIPT
        bpy.ops.text.save_as(filepath=str(file_destination)+'\\'+str(py_filename),
        hide_props_region=True,
        check_existing=True,
        filter_blender=False,
        filter_backup=False,
        filter_image=False,
        filter_movie=False,
        filter_python=True,
        filter_font=False,
        filter_sound=False,
        filter_text=True,
        filter_archive=False,
        filter_btx=False,
        filter_collada=False,
        filter_alembic=False,
        filter_usd=False,
        filter_folder=True,
        filter_blenlib=False,
        filemode=9,
        display_type='DEFAULT',
        sort_method='FILE_SORT_ALPHA')

    i+=1
```

This keeps giving me an error:

> Error: Unable to save '': Invalid argument
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\Sync Cloud\Sync\BLENDER PYTHON SCRIPTS\Save Scripts.blend\Export Scripts.py", line 43, in 
>     File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
>   RuntimeError: Error: Unable to save '': Invalid argument
>
> Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: Sure. `bpy.data.texts` returns a collection of all text files created. Can you elaborate what you'd like to do? Text files going to be stored to the blend by default so I don't get your q.

Comment: Thank you! this is what I needed. I'm writing a script to save all my scripts in a blender file.

Comment: They are already stored per .blend, I don't get your idea. Why you need to save them twice? I'd suggest add the current state of your code to the post so we can have a look at @TYLRwithspaces

Comment: @brockmann I updated the post with my script. I keep getting that error,                            should I make a new post? I'm new here. Im new to scripting in blender and python but ive been writing a lot of scripts across a bunch of different blender files for a project. I've been updating the scripts as I go, its been a learning process so sometimes I mess things up. I want to use this as a way to easily backup all my scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)**

Here is a script that writes all text files in blend with suffix `.py` to a designated folder.

IMO there is no need to timestamp a file name, since it is given a date when written to or touched.  Timestamp a containing folder name if need be.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

destination_folder = "/tmp/texts"
df = Path(destination_folder)

#create if doesn't exist
if not df.exists():
    df.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

for text in bpy.data.texts:
    p = df / text.name
    if p.suffix == ".py":
        p.write_text(text.as_string())
```

On getting the path from the blend file name

```
>>> bpy.data.filepath
'/home/batfinger/Documents/blender/tests/snurf.blend'

>>> Path(bpy.data.filepath)
PosixPath('/home/batfinger/Documents/blender/tests/snurf.blend')

>>> bp = Path(bpy.data.filepath)

>>> bp.stem
'snurf'
```

If the file is new and has not been saved the datapath will be "". The folder will revert to the base path blender was started from. In my case blender was launched from the terminal in the folder "foo".

```
>>> dp = Path('')
>>> dp
PosixPath('.')

>>> dp.absolute()
PosixPath('/home/batfinger/foo')
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. But I'm getting an error when I try to make the directory. <<File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\python\lib\pathlib.py", line 1258, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'D:\\Sync Cloud\\Sync\\BLENDER PYTHON SCRIPTS\\Mass Saves By Date\\Save Scripts\\Save Scripts_2020-02-21_15:23'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console>>

Comment: Actually i figured it out