# How do I add a button to the 'fileselect' panel?

Tags: python, scripting

I have python code that displays the 'fileselect' panel to retrieve and image file. I would like to add a button and event code to this panel. Currently I initiate the 'fileselect' panel with the following after setting it up.

```
context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
```

Thanks

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6933/3710, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43828/3710, http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26906/3710

Comment: Looking at your link helped and I got something to work, thanks